# Angular14 How to iterate through a strictly typed FormGroups controls

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I am using Angular v14 and the upgrading my formGroups to strictly typed. I have a block of logic that if executed, iterates through all the controls of a FormGroup and does *something - this part isn't important as I can't even get to this part*

Here is what I have tried:

**Form Setup**

```
export interface ExampleForm{
    q1 : FormControl<string | null>,
    q2: FormControl<string | null>,
    q3: FormControl<string | null>,
    ...
}

...

exampleForm= this.fb.group<ExampleForm>({
    q1 : new FormControl('',[Validators.required,]),
    q2 : new FormControl('',[Validators.required,]),
    q3 : new FormControl('',[Validators.required,]),
  })
//the form is much longer but shortening for example purposes

...
```

**Broken Logic Here**

```
ngOnInit(): void {
    if (someLogic) {
      Object.keys(this.exampleForm.controls).forEach((key) => {
        this.exampleForm.controls[key].setValue("some value");
        //other logic here using key
      });
    }
  }
```

**Error i receive:**

*Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type 'string' can't be used to index type '{ q1: FormControl<string | null>; q2: FormControl<string | null>; q3: FormControl<string | null>;*

**What I have tried:**

```
if (someLogic) {
      Object.keys(this.exampleForm.controls).forEach((key:string) => {
        this.exampleForm.controls[key].setValue("some value");
        //other logic here using key
      });
    }

...

if (someLogic) {
      Object.keys(this.exampleForm.controls).forEach((key : string | null) => {
        this.exampleForm.controls[key].setValue("some value");
        //other logic here using key
      });
    }
//with this the above error goes away but instead I get a new one saying Type 'null' cannot be used as an index type.
```

Also I need to use the forEach block on these groups for other reasons than just setting a value so **patchValue()** won't suffice.

Comment: why not use `this.exampleForm.get(key).setValue("some value");`? NOTE: you can use also [patchValue](https://angular.io/api/forms/FormGroup#patchValue) or [setValue](https://angular.io/api/forms/FormGroup#setvalue) over the "whole" form. You use `this.exampleForm.setValue(full_object)` if full_object has all the properties of the formGroup and `this.exampleForm.patchValue(partial_object)` if not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem is that the form has the keys `q1`, `q2`, `q3`, etc. but you are trying to index it with a `string`. Try this:

```js
for (const [key, control] of Object.entries(this.exampleForm.controls)) {
  control.setValue('some value');
  // ...
}
```

Since the compiler knows that `this.exampleForm.controls` looks like this:

```
{
  q1: ...,
  q2: ...,
  q3: ...
}
```

Only keys in the type `'q1' | 'q2' | 'q3'` are guaranteed to have a value when used to index it.

Comment: This works, didn't think you use entries instead of controls, thanks.